# App running but setImageBitMap() is not generating QR code

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to do an android app. It is a basic app for generating QR codes. Before, the app works perfectly fine by just using a 'Generate QR Code' button.
But I decided to put the generator QR image inside a `ViewPager` that is controlled by a TabLayout.

I was able to configure 2 tabs and each will be having a unique QR code.

Here's the content of each Tab fragment:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/action_text"
        android:textFontWeight="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/receive_QR"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_text"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
```

**NOTE: THE SECOND FRAGMENT's IMAGE VIEW HAS send_QR id**

Here's the code snippet of the java file:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    private static final android.os.Environment Environment = null;
    String TAG = "GenerateQRCode";
    ImageView receiveQR;
    String savePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/QRCode/";
    Bitmap bitmap;
    QRGEncoder receiveQrgEncoder;
    int smallerDimension;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        receiveQR = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.receive_QR);

        smallerDimension = (100 * 3) / 5;

        receiveQrgEncoder = new QRGEncoder("QR LOGIC GOES HERE", null, QRGContents.Type.TEXT, smallerDimension);
        try{
            bitmap = receiveQrgEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
            receiveQR.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (WriterException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    }


}
```

What am I missing?
Thank you very much for your time and assistance on this matter.

Comment: Noted @Zoe. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only because you're returning a new inflated View again on the last line of your `onCreateView()`. So, your binded view is reset hence the `receiveQR` will be emptied. The following code is incorrect:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        receiveQR = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.receive_QR);

        ...

        // you're returning a new inflated view here which is incorrect.
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    }
}
```

You need to return the previous inflated view, something like this:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        receiveQR = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.receive_QR);

        ...

        return view;

    }


}
```